# ScrollView animation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[Drawing of the animation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M1bg.png) I am trying to make this animation (shown in the picture) where the cards come from the left and start scrolling up. Each card is made with a Container.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return SingleChildScrollView(
     scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
     child: Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
       child: Column(
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
         children: [
           CardViewer(
             child: Container(
               padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100, horizontal: 20),
                 child: Header()),
           ),
           CardViewer(
             child: Container(
                 padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100, horizontal: 20),
                 child: Header()),
           ),
           CardViewer(
             child: Container(
                 padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100, horizontal: 20),
                 child: Header()),
           ),
         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
```

Where CardViewer is the class I created that simulates the card and Header() is the content

Answer (score 0):

The following code does exactly what you want:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LeftToRight extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final int delay;

  LeftToRight({@required this.child, this.delay});

  @override
  _DelayedAnimationState createState() => _DelayedAnimationState();
}

class _DelayedAnimationState extends State<LeftToRight>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<Offset> _animOffset;
  // Animation

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200));
    final curve =
        CurvedAnimation(curve: Curves.decelerate, parent: _controller);
    _animOffset =
        Tween<Offset>(begin: const Offset(-1.0, 0.0), end: Offset.zero)
            .animate(curve);

    if (widget.delay == null) {
      _controller.forward();
    } else {
      Timer(Duration(milliseconds: widget.delay), () {
        _controller.forward();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FadeTransition(
      child: SlideTransition(
        position: _animOffset,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
      opacity: _controller,
    );
  }
}
```

You just need to make your Container() a child of the LeftToRight(), so you would have something like this:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return SingleChildScrollView(
     scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
     child: Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
       child: Column(
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
         children: [
           CardViewer(
             child: Container(
               padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100, horizontal: 20),
                 child: Header()),
           ),
           CardViewer(
             child: Container(
                 padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100, horizontal: 20),
                 child: Header()),
           ),
           LeftToRight(
             delay: 600, //specify the delay that you want in milliseconds
             child: CardViewer(
             child: Container(
                 padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100, horizontal: 20),
                 child: Header()),
           ),
           )
         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can I make it happen once I have scrolled down? I have been able to do it with a boolean (and a button) but it should be done automatically